# Correct usage of utc timestamps and local datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time

I've used `time.time()` to generate timestamps across client apps. These timestamps are accumulated and sent in batches to an external and independent location.

While rendering these timestamps back on the client application I intend to use `datetime.fromtimestamp(ts_from_external_source)` in order to create local `datetime` objects, without defining the timezone so it assumes the local by default.

Is this the recommended way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's a good way of doing it: you store "Unix epoch" style times, and convert them to whatever local time you need before displaying them.

Comment: Yes. But in this case the fromtimestamp would call the C function localtime() and this should automatically resolve the timezone correct? I just need to know if i should worry about timezones(or even DSTs for that matter).

Comment: I think you're doing everything right.  And yes, localtime() knows about DST etc.

Comment: [`datetime.fromtimestamp()` may fail in some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27835492/4279)

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to use a naive datetime object that represents local time if you *use it only for displaying* the timestamp.

`datetime.fromtimestamp(ts_from_external_source)` should work during DST transitions (local time may be ambiguous but POSIX timestamps are not if we ignore leap seconds). Though it might fail for dates from the past/future if the local timezone had/will have different UTC offset at the time *and* the underlying C library does not use a historical timezone database such as [the tz database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html) (Linux, OS X use it. python on Windows -- might not).

`datetime.fromtimestamp(ts_from_external_source)` should be ok for recent dates in most timezones.

You could use `Europe/Moscow` timezone with dates from 2010-2015 for testing (the timezone rules had changed in that period).

You could provide the tz database using `pytz` module:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

tz = get_localzone() # get the local timezone as pytz timezone (with historical data)
utc_dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc) + timedelta(seconds=ts_from_external_source)
dt = utc_dt.astimezone(tz)
```

Or:

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts_from_external_source, tz)
```

Run [these tests](http://bugs.python.org/review/22791/diff/13230/Lib/test/datetimetester.py) to see whether `datetime + timedelta` and `fromtimestamp()` produce different results on your platform.

Comment: I would **not** have seen that coming. When you mentioned that the timezone rules changed, does this happen often? Luckily enough I haven't yet captured the timestamps, but I would be concerned if they changed again in the future.

Comment: @farthVader: timestamps do *not* depend on the local timezone e.g., `0` is the Epoch (ignoring non-POSIX timestamps or "right" timezones) -- it is the same moment around the world (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`) -- whatever a local clock may show (e.g., 1am in Paris, 10am in Melbourne, etc). [There were 10 releases of the tz database in 2014.](https://github.com/eggert/tz/releases)

Comment: My bad. If I'm dealing with a naive local datetime object, should I be concerned about the timezone rules changing? If it's not too much, could you point me to the articles depicting when, why and how timezone rules change?

Comment: I'm trying to establish this- "the timestamps are generated on the client, sent to a server, and are rendered back on the client at a later point."
If timezone rules changed, and if the underlying OS lib is incapable of dealing with that, then wouldn't it affect other dependents as well?

Comment: @farthVader: Short answer: everything is broken. You can implement more or less robust solution: you can find a sweet spot for your application (a balance): the correctness vs. the complexity. A change in timezone rules may change how your timezone-aware datetime object is converted to UTC and therefore you might need to store both UTC time and local time (at the time of collection). Read [the first link in the answer](http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html) -- it links to other resources too. Or you could [watch a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).

Comment: I repeat, just in case: *"if the underlying OS lib is incapable of dealing with that"* -- it is enough to install `pytz` to get access to the tz database in Python (On my machine, it uses system-wide tz database that is updated automatically by the distribution)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastien: Roger. 
`dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts_from_external_source, tz)` will definitely work for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69563/discussion-between-farthvader-and-j-f-sebastian).